# Python : from module import function

Tags: python

I am practicing how to make a module and how to import a function of a module.

My code and the output are as follows.

I imported only the function 'fun1' of the module, but as shown in the output, printing 'the end' is also unintentionally imported.

I want to know the reason why 'the end' is also printed.

code of  'module1.py'

```
def func1(num) : 
    return num+1

print("the end")
```

code of 'body.py'

```
from module1 import fun1 

fun1(3)
```

output

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\body.py 
the end

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Virtual Environment

'body.py' and 'module1.py' are in the same directory 'pythonProject'.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly  But I imported only the 'fun1' part.. Shouldn't it not be imported because the printing part is outside fun1?

Comment: I tested it, and it works as intended for me.